# On the countable sum theorem

Tags: general-topology, dimension-theory-analysis

[image]

I am trying to understand the above theorem. I get most of the proof but I have trouble understanding why the functions $g_i$ were introduced. I mean why can't we just define $g:X\rightarrow S^n$ by $g(x)=f_i(x)$ if $x\in B_i\cup \bar{V}_i$ instead of $g(x)=g_i(x)$ if $x\in V_i$. What is the need of the $g_i$ functions?

Source: A. R. Pears, Dimension theory of general spaces.

Comment: There are numerous kinds of topological dimension, including the small inductive dimension, the large inductive dimension, the covering dimension, and others.  I don't want to study this without knowing what dim X means here as I dk what is being attempted. SO:  What is the definition of dim X?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet, there are many definitions of $\dim X$ but the one relevant here is "Let $(X,T)$ normal topological space. Then $\dim⁡X≤n$ if and only if for each closed set $A$ in $X$, each continuous function $f:A→S^n$ has an extension $g:X→S^n$."

Comment: @DanielWainfleet, also "Let $X$ be a normal space and $A,B$ are closed set in $X$, such that  $\dim⁡ A≤n$. Then every function $f:B→S^n$ can be extend over the union of $A$ and a closed neighborhood of $B$."

Comment: @DanielWainfleet, Let $A$ be a closed subset of a normal space $X$. Then every continuous function $f:A→S^n$ can be extended to some neighborhood of $A$.